# Update Quantity on Hand via XMLRPC and PHP odoo V14

Tags: php, odoo

I want to change a "Quantity On Hand" field so I trying this code:

```html
   $change_id = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,
        'stock.change.product.qty', 'create',
        array(array(
            'product_id'=>11745,
            'location_id'=>15,
            'new_quantity'=>26,
            )
        ));
        $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password, 'stock.change.product.qty', 'change_product_qty', [$change_id]);
```

But it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For changing stock quantity for products you need to create a `stock.quant` record.

```html
   $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,
        'stock.quant', 'create',
        array(array(
            'product_id'=>11745,
            'location_id'=>15,
            'inventory_quantity'=>26,
            )
        ));
```

Also keep in mind that directly changing the stock quantity is not recommended, it should be changed from a purchase order or a sale order or from production or inventory adjustments based on the situation.

Comment: Thanks, Mehrdad for your answer, But your code is for adding a new quantity record not for update the previous one, I'm asking for updating the quantity, So do you have any idea after creating a new record how can I update the Quantity On Hand?

Comment: In Odoo 14 if you try to create a new `stock.quant` record with same `product_id` and `location_id` of an existing record, It will update the existing record instead of creating another one.So creating a new `stock.quant` for a product with the same location will result in updating the previous one. For older versions I'm not sure, So you can first call the `search` method and get the id of existing `stock.quant` record and then call the `write` method to update the `inventory_quantity` field.